# Android programmatically manipulate Browser History for unittests

Tags: android, browser-history

I want to unittest my classes, for that purpose I first call:

```
Browser.clearHistory(getContext().getContentResolver());
```

But how can I now add some entries as test-data for my unittest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've created a function for that, which calls urls in chrome

```
private void openUrlInChrome(String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");

    // force system to use chrome and not standard browser
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));

    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");

    // is needed because this test is not an activity
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
    // wait until chrome has opened the pages
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```